# how to make the component name to be variable in react route, passing it as parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

how can I make here the component name to be variable in every call, so that I can reuse my code and render a different component everytime I call the function, help please???Like I want the sayhello to have parameters, and then use that parameter as component where the VARIABLE is:

```
class Plantel extends Component{

    state= {sayhello: false}

    sayhello = ()  => {

        return (
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/groups' component={VARIABLE}/>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>);
    }

    render (){

        return  (<div label="Princ">
            <Ribbon breakpoint="lg" height="8rem">
                <RibbonGroup title="Ciclos" colClass="col-1">
                    <RibbonGroupItem colClass="col-12" >
                        <RibbonButton onClick={() => this.setState({sayhello: true}) }>  ✏️<div>Cicle</div></RibbonButton>
                    </RibbonGroupItem>
```

Comment: You mean to say you need to render a different component on groups route. How do you determine the component. Or better what do you do if the user directly visits the groups route

Comment: Hi Shubham, the path will also become a second parameter, lets say I want to be able to give those two parameters and they will change accordingly, but I dont know how to do it. I want to provide those parameter to sayhello method, but I dont know where to put them and how to call them, ive tried just put them in the parenthesis but it does not work with setState.